# Tensorflow - Block Update of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, block, slice, assignment-operator

x is a tensor of shape [32,32,3]

Y is a tensor of shape [1,320,320,3]

can we update the Y, Y[0,:32,:32,:] = x as a tensorflow operation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Did you test it at all?

Slices are tensors too. Use:

```
Y[0,:32,:32,:].assign(x)
```

Example in 1D so that we can clearly see what is happening:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.Variable(np.zeros((2,)))
Y = tf.Variable(np.ones((10,)))

block_update = Y[4:6].assign(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print('old', Y.eval(sess))
    sess.run(block_update)
    print('new', Y.eval(sess))
```

Output:

```
old [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
new [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

Answer (score 0):

gen_array_ops.inplace_update is likely what you want.

`from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_array_ops import inplace_update`

Here is the official docstring

```
def inplace_update(x, i, v, name=None):
  r"""Updates specified rows 'i' with values 'v'.

  Computes `x[i, :] = v; return x`.

  Originally this function is mutative however for compilation we make this
  operation create / operate on a copy of `x`.

  Args:
    x: A `Tensor`. A tensor of type `T`.
    i: A `Tensor` of type `int32`.
      A vector. Indices into the left-most dimension of `x`.
    v: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `x`.
      A `Tensor` of type T. Same dimension sizes as x except the first dimension, which must be the same as i's size.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `x`.
  """
```